# Powershell SMO: This method does not support scripting data

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smo

I want to generate an import script for a MSSQL DB via Powershell (related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38633990)).
I tried doing this:

```
#Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

$DB_NAME = "<<dbName>>"

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | Out-Null

$srv = new-object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Server" "<<server>>"
$conContext = $srv.ConnectionContext
$conContext.LoginSecure = $false
$conContext.Login = "<<user>>"
$conContext.Password = "<<password>>"
$srv = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($conContext)
$srv.SetDefaultInitFields([Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.View], "IsSystemObject")

$db = $srv.databases[$DB_NAME]

$scripter = new-object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter" $srv

$scripter.Options.ScriptSchema = $false
$scripter.Options.ScriptData = $true
$scripter.Options.ScriptDrops = $false

$scripter.Script($db)
```

But executing this throws an error:

```
"This method does not support scripting data"
```

I also tried to set the output file option but this doesn't change anything.

Can you tell me what I did wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Per the error, `Scripter.Script` does not support scripting data. This is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms209761). What isn't documented is what you're supposed to use instead, but it's [`EnumScript`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc285610):

```
$scripter.EnumScript(@($db.Tables))
```

You must pass the tables, since simply scripting the database will yield nothing (as, technically, the database itself contains no data, its tables do).

(The `@()` forcibly converts the `Tables` collection to an array, since that's what `EnumScript` expects.)

Comment: Hi and thanks for your great answer! This sounds like it could solve my problem. Unfortunately now I get this error: Ausnahme beim Aufrufen von "EnumScript" mit 1 Argument(en):  "Script failed for Server 'xxx'. "
In ...
+ $scripter.EnumScript(@($db.Tables))
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailedOperationException   Do you know what causes this exception? Greetings!

Comment: No, and it has nothing to do with `EnumScript` itself -- I know because I verified this code works against a reachable database instance.

Comment: Hi - I fugured out what went wrong: I want to use to set $scripter.Options.ScriptSchema = $false but without the schema I get this error. Is there a way to just script the data? And I need to order the tables in a way that there are no conflicts with foreign keys. Currently the tables are scripted alphabetically but this will throw errors when importing them into an empty DB...

Comment: @C.M. Sounds like you've got some more questions... feel free to post them. Comments aren't the way to go for that. You may want to make the question more general to prevent everything from devolving into an individual debugging session.

Comment: +1, Super helpful, replacing `Script()` with `EnumScript()` allows [scripting objects as individual files](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12950744/3936440) with data.